# Conditional formatting based on adjacent cell value even when the first adjacent cell in row is blank

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I would like to colour cell C3 red, as the value is less than the next filled cell on row 3 (E3).

[image: Gym Log]

Comment: Create a new rule applied on cell C3, choose `Format only cells that contains`, choose `Value`, choose `less than`, type in `=E3`. If you want to use a rule instead, use `=C3<E3` (assuming you are still applying it to cell C3).

Comment: Thanks for the help. What I'm trying to do is to apply the same condition to each cell in column C based on the next available adjacent cell in its row that has a value. i.e. if I enter a value in C13, the cell will format itself based on cell H13. Hope that makes sense?

Comment: Now, that's make the problem more interesting. I'll take a look.

Comment: How large is the table? From column C to which column?

Comment: @EvilBlueMonkey column W

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need custom formula in the formatting rules for range `C2:W`.

And you can use the formula below for green:

```
=and(not(isblank(C2)),C2>index(filter(D2:$W2,arrayformula(not(isblank(D2:$W2))))),1,1)
```

And make another conditional formatting rule with the same range and change `>` accordingly for red.

Note that the equal case does not have formatting in your example.

---

To understand why, there are a few components at work. I'll give an outline in case OP or any passer-by wants one.

First is how conditional formatting in Google Sheet works. I will be brief here. The range we put in the rule is `C2:W`. Google Sheet will use the beginning cell in that range as a reference. For `C2:W`, the 1st cell is `C2`. In the formula, the cells are read in terms of relative position to that reference cell. So when evaluating formatting for cell `C2`, it treats the formula as is. But, for example, when evaluating formatting for cell `C3`, Google Sheet iterates all non-fixed ranges by 1 row. Another example: for `D3`, all non-fixed ranges are iterated by 1 row and 1 column.

Whenever the formula evaluates to `true`, the format will be applied -- although that is subject to further formatting if you have subsequent formatting rules which apply to the given cell.

Next are the components of the conditional formula.

`not(isblank(C2))` checks for blank cells and makes the whole formula only true when the cell is non-blank.

For `filter()` usage, please consult [official documentation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197?hl=en). I will explain how `filter()` is applied to your example.

In our use, we are trying to rid of empty cells in the range that is on the same row as the cell in question and goes from the next column to column W. (I am using column W because there is no known end column in your image. Please adjust to your application accordingly.) Same row as `C2` means row 2. Hence the digit `2` in `D2:$W2`. No `$` sign for row because row index is meant to iterate through our range `C2:W` in the formatting rule. No `$` sign for `D` because we mean 1 column next to the cell in question and the exact column index should iterate. We fix column W because the end column does not evolve and is thus not meant to iterate. Neglecting this will not particularly change the result in your example. However, it is good to be clear with the meanings.

`arrayformula(not(isblank(D2:$W2)))` produces a local row array whose cells are `true`/`false` that each represents whether the corresponding cell is non-blank. `filter()` in turn only keeps cells from `D2:$W2` for cells in `arrayformula(not(isblank(D2:$W2)))` that are `true`.

We only care about the 1st non-blank cell. To retrieve the 1st cell from a (local) array, we use [`index(...,1,1)`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098242?hl=en). (That said, omitting `index()` also happens to work for the 1st cell in particular because when comparing a single cell with `>` or `<` to an array range, only the 1st cell of the array is used.)

Answer (score 0):

Apply a conditional formatting to the range desired (starting from cell C2) using this formula:

```
=IF(C2="",FALSE,OFFSET(C2,0,AGGREGATE(15,6,(COLUMN(D2:W2)-COLUMN(D2)+1)/(D2:W2<>""),1))>C2)
```

Comment: Does not seem to have changed anything? ![sheet](https://ibb.co/f1wz5MF).

Comment: @Cockers: do the other rules override those coming after? I guess that if you write any number greater than 1 (the value in C3) in cell D3, cell C3 will turn pink; if you write 1 in cell D3, cell C3 it will turn blue.

Comment: Google Sheet has `aggregate()`?

Comment: Ah, didn't even notice. The original question had Excel as first tag so i just assumed that the image was on a strange version of Excel 365.

Comment: @EvilBlueMonkey Thank for for taking your time to help out

Comment: @EvilBlueMonkey: ah makes sense. I remember the time when ppl would immediately caution against the mixed-up of the 2 tags. Would help in this case if that continued. Would be a good question-answer separately for Excel tho

Comment: @Argyll: thanks. In fact i intended to leave it just in case someone might find it useful.